# U.s. boiler / Burnham boiler alterations

Tags: hvac, heating, boiler, natural-gas, venting

i have a 203ncl-tei2 boiler installed in danvers Massachusetts. Regular elevation. This boiler also has a failed tejurland (universal control) powerventer motor on it that is only humming, not spinning. Looked for a dead animal, or nest and checked for free spinning of the squirrel cage it was fine. Its installed 3 feet from outside wall on the verticle, (installed wrong also has 2 seperate 90° bends after the venter, not my issue but may have caused the motor to fail). Ontop of the boiler we have a factory automatic damper assy.

So the 2nd part of the problem is I noticed the tei in the model number and assumed this ment i should expect to see a tejurland "universal" power venter installed and i do. I assume because its a universal control unit thats where they went wrong. This unit is atleast 200$ cheaper here than the model burnham uses.  I call burnham and ask what the original power venter model number is and they tell me what some pros may already know, (i didnt), that the tei2 is actually (t)taco, (el)elivation, (2) 2 is 2,000 ft

.Note:he was not.100% sure about the el. He was definetly sure PV would be in the model number and it was not tejurland. There is no chimney on this house, never was. Power venter wall thimble outside is very old definetly older than the 1 year old motor that failed. Burnham also said this is not a boiler that can be converted to a powerventer which is sometging i do not understand. He said if it does not have pv in the model number it should not have one. I have in the past converted a boiler with a factory reccomended power venter after a customer lost the chimney. I called and got lucky they had a option for it. I do not remember manufacturer but do remember also seeing it in the install manual as an addendum or seperate manual.

Is this a fact?

Anyone have experience with this?

What are the ramifications of an elevated boiler installed at sea level?

If i can not find another awnser, i will havemto tell customer they need a new boiler or i will have to walk away.

Why do they not just make an orifice kit for elevated boilers to work properly at higher elevations? Is it because they have to add another section to the boiler so it can put out the same  b.t.u.?  I know there is a reason. Seems like smaller orifice would fix the air fuel ratio along with a regulator adjustment. Its to simple of an awnser knowing that manufacturers make a complete different boiler for higher elevations.

[image]!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've removed your duplicate images, but for us to understand you you'll have to spend some time editing that wall of text. It's hard to read, and makes it hard to answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: The top of the post was removed by the system, was that what you ment?

Comment: Refular elevation would refer to not a high elevation boiler. Because the boiler model number implies it is a higher elevation.